# Hyper-V external IP address

Tags: networking, ip, hyper-v

I am trying to apply an external IP address to my Virtual Host on CentOS, I have purchased a failover IP from my host and they have assigned me a Virtual MAC. I have created a static MAC on the Virtual Host with the MAC the host provided.

I've added the secondary IP address to the vSwitch(External) now I have two IPv4 addresses assigned to the switch. I configure the correct IPv4 within CentOS but I still have no connectivity.

Am I doing this the right way? I want my Windows side of the server to host one of game servers and use CentOS to host a game panel, So I would like them to have two different IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's get on the same page in regards to terminology: When you say you have a Virtual Host do you mean the virtual machine (the guest) running in Hyper-V? If so, please don't call it a Virtual Host as that makes it difficult to understand if you mean Hyper-V (the hypervisor host) or if you mean the virtual machine (the hypervisor guest).

Second, you don't assign ip addresses to your virtual switches, except in the case where you share the virtual switch with the management operating system (the Hyper-V host) for the purpose of using that ip address to connect to and manage the Hyper-V host. When you do this, Hyper-V creates a virtual network adapter to which you assign ip addressing information, again for connecting to and managing the Hyper-V host itself. This ip address isn't related to your virtual machines. You need to assign the ip addresses that you wish to use for the virtual machines in the operating system of the virtual machines.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect terminology, i'm still new to this. 

I have 1 NIC with my default IP Address, I created a vSwitch on that and now the Hyper-V host shares the switch with the Operating System.

Comment: I want to be able to host certain things on the Windows Host and host another Web Server on the Hyper-V machine. The secondary IP I have been given routes to my primary IP address, I just need a way for the machine to route any traffic coming from the secondary IP  to the Hyper-V machine.

Comment: You need to assign the second ip address to the virtual machine, **NOT** to the virtual network adapter that was created by the virtual switch.

Comment: When ever I just add the IP address within the virtual machine I have no connectivity. I did manage to get connectivity with the internal switch but then none of the applications were available externally.

Comment: I did it! Thanks for your help joeqwerty, I set the IP address as the secondary and the gateway to the primary IP's gateway and we are up and running <3

Comment: The problem i'm having now is the Web Server not being accessible outside of the network.